# Get column sum and use to calculate percent of total (mySQL)

Tags: mysql

Here is a very basic look at my table. I have columns 1 and 2 and need to generate column 3. Column 3 is simply the total of the `Number` column for all `Name` divided by `Number` for the given row.

```
| Name          | Number        | % of total  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:      |
| Bob           | 5             |  25         |
| Sally         | 10            |  50         |
| John          | 5             |  25         |
```

I'm struggling with how to get the total of the number row and use this as a value to calculate the rest.

EDIT: I'm looking to do this as a single query instead of two separate if possible.

Comment: Do you have the total sum of the second columns beforehand?

Comment: @SalmonKiller No, I don't. That's the tricky part (for me). Trying to get that value and then use it all in one query.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just need to `CROSS JOIN` the `SUM()` of `Number` column:

```
SELECT Name, Number, Number * 100 / t.s AS `% of total`
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Number) AS s FROM mytable) t
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8e98/1)

Comment: This is working for me...thanks! One question. If I wanted to add a `WHERE` clause (such as `WHERE name="Bob"`), where would that go? I tried to put it after the `FROM mytable`, but getting errors.

Comment: @jonmrich It depends on what you want to filter. Is it the rows on which `SUM` is applied to? Then you have to do it in the `SELECT` of the `CROSS JOIN`. Otherwise `WHERE` has to be placed *after* the `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: As you can imagine, my actually table is a lot more complicated than this. I multiple columns with the same name (representing the same person) and I need to add each of these instances together (e.g., the total for Bob) and divide this by the total of the `Number` column. This is where I'm getting hung up I think.

Comment: @jonmrich I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8e98/2) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks...I got it all working with some `group by` and `where` in the right places.

Comment: I'd avoid running a subquery for the sake of a sum.  It's very wasteful on resources.  See AdamMC331's response for a much nicer solution (nicer on the server, that is)

Answer (score 6):

If I were doing this, I would start by storing a variable that held the total, like this:

```
SET @total := (SELECT SUM(number) FROM myTable);
```

Once I had that variable, I could run a query that got the percentage for each row like this:

```
SELECT name, number, (number / @total) * 100 AS percentage
FROM myTable;
```

If you don't want to use a variable, you can just move that subquery into your select statement:

```
SELECT name, number, (number / (SELECT SUM(number) FROM myTable)) * 100 AS percentage
FROM myTable;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/146f9/3) example with each approach.

Comment: I've never worked with storing a variable. How long is it stored? Can I write over it? Do I need to run these in separate queries? Many questions...

Comment: @jonmrich They are if I'm not mistaken run separately, which I see now in your edit you might not want that. It's more useful in a stored procedure I believe. As far as how long its stored, I'm not sure. It might just be your current section

Comment: Got it...good thing to know for the future though even if it doesn't apply here.

Comment: To be clear, the @variable in mysql lasts the term of your connection and are local to that connection. So if you connect, set the variable, then continue running queries using that variable, you will not have a problem. Further, if you have multiple connections, all setting and using that same variable name, they each have their own "copy" and will not update/change that same variable on another connection.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Dev!

Answer (score 5):

You can get it with a subselect:

```
SELECT Name, Number, Number * 100 / (select sum(Number) FROM MYTABLE) AS '% of total'
FROM mytable
```