# Calculating the percentage between two columns that used a TOP clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server that does the following:

1. Gets the top 5 importers
2. Calculates the sum of import value and import volume for each
3. Calculates the percentage against the overall total import value and volume

Here's my query:

```
    DECLARE @OVERALL_TOTAL_VAL AS BIGINT
    DECLARE @OVERALL_TOTAL_VOL AS BIGINT

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- GET TOTAL VALUE AND VOLUME FROM ALL IMPORTERS TO USE FOR GETTING THE %
    SET @OVERALL_TOTAL_VAL = (SELECT SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) 
                                FROM [DBO].[ALERT]
                                WHERE IMPORTERCODE != 0)
    SET @OVERALL_TOTAL_VOL = (SELECT SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME)
                                FROM [DBO].[Alert]
                                WHERE IMPORTERCODE != 0)

    -- GET TOP 5 IMPORTERS
    SELECT 
        TOP 5 IMPORTERCODE,
        @OVERALL_TOTAL_VAL TOTAL_VAL,
        @OVERALL_TOTAL_VOL TOTAL_VOL,
        SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) TOTAL_IMPORT_VALUE, 
        SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) TOTAL_IMPORT_VOL, 
        --((SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) / @OVERALL_TOTAL_VAL) * 100) NET_VAL,
        --((SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) / @OVERALL_TOTAL_VOL) * 100) NET_VOL,
        --(((SELECT SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) 
        -- FROM [DBO].[ALERT]
        -- WHERE IMPORTERCODE = A1.IMPORTERCODE
        -- GROUP BY IMPORTERCODE) / @OVERALL_TOTAL_VAL) * 100 ) NET_VAL,
        COUNT(*) ALERT_COUNT
    FROM [DBO].[ALERT] A1

    WHERE IMPORTERCODE != 0
    GROUP BY IMPORTERCODE
    ORDER BY ALERT_COUNT DESC;
```

The commented-out lines were the ones I've tried, but unfortunately did not work. I've also tried cross-joining (via [Get column sum and use to calculate percent of total (mySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509149/get-column-sum-and-use-to-calculate-percent-of-total-mysql)); didn't work as well.

Is this because I have a `TOP 5` in my `SELECT` statement? Is what I'm trying to do possible? Because if not, I'd have to do the percentage calculation in the front-end side of my app, and I want to avoid that if possible.

Please help. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Finally got it to work. Guess there was no need for the parameters after all. Thank you lad2025 for the help!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TOP 5 IMPORTERCODE,
    SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY IMPORTERCODE) AS TOTAL_IMPORT_VAL,
    SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) OVER(PARTITION BY IMPORTERCODE) AS TOTAL_IMPORT_VOL,
    100.0 * SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY IMPORTERCODE)/
            SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER() AS NET_VAL,
    100.0 * SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) OVER (PARTITION BY IMPORTERCODE)/
            SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) OVER() AS NET_VOL,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY IMPORTERCODE) ALERT_COUNT
FROM [DBO].[ALERT]
WHERE IMPORTERCODE != 0
ORDER BY ALERT_COUNT DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [windowed functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 IMPORTERCODE,
   SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER(PARTIITON BY IMPORTERCODE) AS total_import_value
   SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) OVER(PARTIITON BY IMPORTERCODE) AS total_import_volumne,
   100.0 * SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER(PARTIITON BY IMPORTERCODE)/
           SUM(IMPORTEDVALUE) OVER() AS [% value percentage],
   100.0 * SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) OVER(PARTIITON BY IMPORTERCODE)/
           SUM(IMPORTEDVOLUME) AS [% volume percentage]
FROM [DBO].[ALERT]
WHERE IMPORTERCODE != 0
ORDER BY total_import_value DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! It's my first time seeing `OVER()` used in a query. Is this what you mean by windowed functions? What does it do?

Comment: It's working! I had to modify it a bit because I needed the result of `COUNT()`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DeeJ. Yes, `OVER` is for windowed functions.