# Get column sum from two tables and use to calculate percent of total

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, window-functions

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509149/get-column-sum-and-use-to-calculate-percent-of-total-mysql) but in my case, I get the columns from two tables.

My original query:

```
SELECT price, qty, price*qty as total
FROM  tableprices AS t1, tableqty AS t2 
WHERE t1.codigo = t2.codigo
```

Then, I would like to get another column with the percent from total in the table in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    price, 
    qty, 
    price * qty as total,
    100.0 * price * qty / sum(price * qty) over() percent_total
FROM  tableprices AS t1
INNER JOIN tableqty AS t2 ON t1.codigo = t2.codigo
```

Note that this uses standard, explicit join syntax (with the `ON` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `FROM` clause): this old syntax has fallen out of favor decades ago, and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Use window fucntions:

```
SELECT price, qty, price*qty as total,
       (price * qty) / sum(price * qty) over () as ratio
FROM tableprices p join
     tableqty q 
     ON q.codigo = p.codigo;
```

Notice that I also fixed your archaic `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Very thank you. On the other hand, I have "only" over 50 functions more or less using commas. I have work for tomorrow ;-)